How to get values from properties file in Ktor?
I've generated a Ktor project and would like to configure it to connect to my Postgres database without exposing my credentials.
Among the results I found, the configuration was either done with hard-coded data:
val database = Database.connect(
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",
    user = "root",
    driver = "org.h2.Driver",
    password = "",
)

or using system environment variables: How to connect to Postgres with Kotlin/Ktor with plugin start
If possible, I would like to avoid using these methods.
From what I understood, to use variables without exposing them, I had to create a .properties file, which I did. However, I don't know how to load its values into a Ktor project. I would like my application.yaml file to look like this:
postgres:
    url: $POSTGRES_URL
    user: $POSTGRES_USER
    password: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD

I could also put my hard-coded identifiers in this file and add it to my .gitignore file. But I deduce that this isn't the right thing to do, as the documentation mentions that environment variables should be used.
What I've tried:

I have created configuration files development.properties and production.properties at the root of the project with the following contents:

POSTGRES_URL=
POSTGRES_USER=
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=


In my Databases.kt file, I tried to retrieve the values from my properties file, but they are null

fun Application.configureDatabases() {
    val properties = Properties()
    val propertiesFile = File("development.properties")

    if (!propertiesFile.exists()) {
        throw FileNotFoundException("Postgres configuration file not found")
    }

    val url = properties.getProperty("POSTGRES_URL")
    val user = properties.getProperty("POSTGRES_USER")
    val password = properties.getProperty("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")

    println(url)
    println(user)
    println(password)

//    val database =
//        Database.connect(
//            url,
//            user = user,
//            driver = "org.h2.Driver",
//            password = password
//        )
}


I suggest reading the documentation (https://ktor.io/docs/server-configuration-file.html#read-configuration-in-code).

Sorry, I had read it before, but I didn't understand it that way. Thanks a lot @AlekseiTirman

Can you explain what exactly you didn't understand?

Typically, the doc shows that it is possible to use environment variables. I thought it was the system variable, but if you're referring me to the doc, then that's not the case. However, it doesn't show the file where we store our environment variables. I'll keep reading the docs, there's bound to be something I've missed.

Do you need to read Properties (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) or the Ktor's configuration (HOCON or YAML)?

I need to store my database credentials without exposing them. If I'm not mistaken, in Kotlin you create an .properties file. I could add my application.yaml file to my .gitignore, but I doubt it would be a good practice.

You can substitute parameters with environment variables to hide the secret values (https://ktor.io/docs/server-configuration-file.html#environment-variables).

Do you mean environment variables from my system? Isn't there another way to do it? By the way, I've edited my post and added more infotmations.

Yes, I mean the environment variables. However, you can get the configuration values using the API described in https://ktor.io/docs/server-configuration-file.html#read-configuration-in-code.

You mean using another application.yaml file or adding the existing one in my .gitignore

I mean to put settings into an existing application.yaml file and use names with a dollar sign there to make the values resolvable from the environment variables.

So I have no choice but to use my system's environment variables? Isn't it possible to use the equivalent of an .env file as with dotenv? Thanks for your help, I'm thinking of using Docker. And sorry again, I'm really struggling with the android ecosystem.

You have to use environment variables or access some storage with the secrets. Can you describe the expected behavior of the solution?

I'm used to working in a JavaScript ecosystem where it's common to use an .env file at the root of the project in which we store our environment variables. If I use Docker, I could also use an .env file.

You can use dotenv-kotlin (https://github.com/cdimascio/dotenv-kotlin).

I also saw that, but I didn't think it was possible to use it in a Ktor project. Thanks!
